# Ways to store variables throughout the life time of android app in phone

Tags: android, global-variables

I am new to Android. I am building a test application where I need to store a variable's value say, `strength` of the user. I want to increase or decrease this `strength`'s value whenever user uses the app. And after user closes the app and reopens it on next day, he should find the same value of `strength`.

One way I can think of is to store a local db in phone and read/write each time into that, since there are hardly 3 to 4 such variables. So db is not a good option I guess. 
Other one I thought was to use `android.app.Application` class but I am not able to get what I want from that. Can we actually do it using `android.app.Application`? Or then any other method for 3 to 4 variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store your variable inside shared preferences. For example, set it like:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("DATA",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("STRENGTH",yourVar).apply();
```

Then get it out using:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("DATA",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
strength = sharedPreferences.getString("STRENGTH",null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). SharedPreference provides an easy mechanism to persist a value across the life of an app.

Answer (score 0):

Write an XML file in the application directory that the application can read on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Use application class when our app is open read last state and store your data in shared preference, and you are right db is not good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Like you suggested, you can use an [SQLite database](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) to store a table regarding the users. Although, you might only have one variable, strength, associated with each user now but if there's potential for more associated values that you want to store regarding the user, I'll recommend using an SQLite database.

Another option you can use is [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html), it allows you to store key value pairs. So in your case, each strength value can correspond to a username.

If you haven't learned the different storage options for Android, I'll recommend you taking a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Hope this helps!